# Copy Text from WYSIWYG-Editor and don't allow CSS-inheritance

Tags: html, css, inheritance, format

I have a big Problem with CSS and the resulting inheritance. I want to copy a Text from a WYSIWYG-Editor in an other div element and show this text exactly like its formatted in the Editor. But when i copy the text in a grid, which has lot of div elements an lot of css styles, the text gets formatted because of the CSS-inheritance. Can i disable this behavior in some way?

Otherwise an italic styled text isn't always italic or bold and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Put an `<iframe>` wrapper around it - it will stop all styles that are not loaded in it. Than load the same css you use for your WYSIWYG and load it into `<iframe>` head.

Comment: I tried this behaviour but i think i have to give the iframe a source. it's not enough to put an div element and a text into it. i won't be displayed.

Comment: But I don't have a site which ich can reference or an document. I only have an html code. So, how can i do that?

Comment: Load the editor code in a separate control and than load that control as src for your iframe.